# How do you share a Google Drive **folder** with a non-Google user while still restricting access to that folder (not using Anyone can access/public)?

Tags: google-drive

Basicaly what the question asks.

How do you share a Google Drive **folder** with a non-Google user while still restricting access to that folder (not using Anyone can access/public)?

Comment: You must ask that person to sign in to Google first(Can be done using a non-gmail account too) — and then add his email in the "shared with" section. This *must* work. The person can later either delete the google account or let the account be as is

Comment: @SaaranshGarg thanks for that input, however it confirms what I was scared of, i.e. Google does try to Googlize everything and everyone. I'm setting up a nextcloud server right now, I had enough :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is not possible...